# high school math question, algebra, contest question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of two distinct real number is a positive integer and the sum of their squares is 2. Compute the greater of these two real numbers.
I tried to set up the equations first,:

> $x^2 +y^2 =2\\
> x+y = n,\enspace n \in \mathbb{N}$

Then I have no idea how to solve these two..

Answer (score 4):

$x + y = n, x^2+y^2 = 2 \Rightarrow 2 = (x+y)^2 - 2xy = n^2 - 2xy \Rightarrow n^2-2 = 2xy \leq \dfrac{(x+y)^2}{2} = \dfrac{n^2}{2} \Rightarrow n^2 \leq 4 \Rightarrow n \leq 2$. Can you continue ?

Comment: You could even use $2xy < \frac{(x+y)^2}{2}$, as $x \neq y$.